# For statement in Unity issue?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to "squeeze" a gameObject. When distance starts to be 6.98, execute this code: "The smaller the distance between gameObject1 and gameObject2, the thinner and longer this gameObject is". Somehow, this code has no effect. Why?

```
public Transform gameObject1;
public Transform gameObject2;

void Update () 
{
     float distance_squeeze = Vector3.Distance(gameObject1.position, gameObject2.position);

     for (distance_squeeze = 6.98f; distance_squeeze > 0; distance_squeeze -= 0.1f) 
     {
          transform.localScale += new Vector3(-0.5F, 0.5F, 0);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the distance between `gameObject1` and `gameObject2` and then setting it equal to `6.98`.
  Try something like:

```
 void Update () 
 {
     float distance_squeeze = Vector3.Distance(gameObject1.position, gameObject2.position);    
     if(distance_squeeze < 6.98F){
         transform.localScale = new Vector3(-distance_squeeze, distance_squeeze, 1);
     }   
 }
```

Comment: Nice catch. But still nothing happens, no effect... Maybe something else is the problem?

Comment: Did you set `gameObject1` and `gameObject2` properly in the inspector?

Comment: Yes. I did set them properly.

Comment: I made it work! This code only sets the gameObject's scale to the distance between gameObject1 and gameObject2. It does not "squeeze".

Comment: I want it to simulate the effect of squeezing. @Pluto